# Google Sheet - Split Cell contents into rows and columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Linked Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2P2V0SCiE7QtK7kdCorpLfYQPFRghKMw4tuCYbqce0/edit?usp=sharing

I have a form that outputs all products and quantities into one cell:

"Product: NF900XC, Quantity: 3
Product: NF900, Quantity: 2
Product: N1930CB, Quantity: 2
Product: N2120, Quantity: 1
Product: NLPCR200, Quantity: 2
Product: N272, Quantity: 2"

I need each Product and Quantity on their own Line with its corresponding associated data collection.

I would like the contents (column O) split into their respective columns:

`**Product** : **Quantity**
     NF900   : 2
     N1930CB : 2
     N2120   : 1
     NLPCR200: 2
     N272    : 2`

I have used `SPLIT(text, delimiter, [split_around_each_character])` command for First Name Last Name but am unsure how to parse the rest of the text into their rows and columns in this situation.

I will also be functionally copying rows with the timestamp in

column A

**Submission Date**

that correspond to the Products:Quantity in cell O

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that I've tested and it works.  The code removes all the words "Product: ", and replaces them with a comma.  Then the code does something similar with the string "Quantity: ", replacing it with an empty string.  Next it creates an array, and converts the array to a two dimensional array, so that the rows and columns can be written all in one action.

```
function convertData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form Submission');

  var data = sh.getRange("O2").getValue();
  //Logger.log(data);
  var firstProductRemoved = data.replace("Product: ", "");
  //Logger.log(firstProductRemoved);

  var allProductReplacedWithComma = firstProductRemoved.replace(/Product: /g,",");
  //Logger.log(allProductReplacedWithComma);

  var allQuantityReplacedWithNothing = allProductReplacedWithComma.replace(/Quantity: /g,"");
  //Logger.log(allQuantityReplacedWithNothing);

  var dataAsArray = allQuantityReplacedWithNothing.split(",");

  var outerArray = [], innerArray = [];
  var i=0;

  for (i=0;i<dataAsArray.length;i+=2) {
    innerArray = []; //reset every loop

    innerArray.push(dataAsArray[i]);
    innerArray.push(dataAsArray[i+1]);
    outerArray.push(innerArray);
  };
  //Logger.log(outerArray);

  var orderItemsSh = ss.getSheetByName('Order Items');
  orderItemsSh.getRange(orderItemsSh.getLastRow()+1, 15,outerArray.length, 2).setValues(outerArray);
};
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you!  How can I compensate you?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and marking the answer as correct.  If you want, you can also upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in a more general solution, rather than one that needs to rely on knowing the specific phrased in the input strings.

This `kvStringToArray()` function will return an array that can be written directly to a spreadsheet use `Range.setvalues()`. It's pure JavaScript, so it can also be used outside of the Google Apps Script environment.

A RegExp is used to successively identify key:value pairs in the input data, and the function assumes that there are "rows" of information that can be identified by repeats of already-discovered "keys".

```js
var formInput = "Product: NF900XC, Quantity: 3 Product: NF900, Quantity: 2 Product: N1930CB, Quantity: 2 Product: N2120, Quantity: 1 Product: NLPCR200, Quantity: 2 Product: N272, Quantity: 2";
snippet.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    kvStringToArray(formInput)));

/**
 * Convert a given string of key:value pairs into a two-dimensional
 * array, with keys as headers, and "items" as rows.
 * From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34847199/1677912
 *
 * @param {string} str    A string containing key:value pairs.
 *
 * @returns {string[][]}  A two-dimensional array of strings.
 */
function kvStringToArray( str ) {
  var re = /\s*(\w*?)\s*:\s*([^,\s]*)/g,  // See https://regex101.com/r/kM7gY1/1
      arr,           // array to capture key:value pairs
      data = [],     // array to return table
      row = [],      // array for building table rows
      headers = [];  // array of unique keys, for table header
  
  // Use a RegEx to identify individual key:value pairs
  while ((arr = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    var key = arr[1];   // $1 matches key
    var value = arr[2]; // $2 matches value
    // Check if we should start a new row
    if (headers.indexOf(key) == 0) {
      data.push(row);
      row = [];
    }
    // Save this value in row
    row.push(value);
    // If this is the first time we've seen this key, add it to headers.
    if (headers.indexOf(key) == -1) headers.push(key);
  }
  data.push(row);  // save last row
  data.unshift(headers); // add headers

  return data;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, this looks nice and an solution to submitting html form data with a dynamic list array.  Thank You!