# How to split cell with delimiter to rows and repeat cells in other columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

I want to split column C that contains data is this format to rows and then repeat data in other columns:

((60665899;); (4328899;););

Is there a google script I could use for this transformation?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far? This looks handy: [Google Sheet - Split Cell contents into rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842658/) or [Duplicate Rows in Google Spreadsheet based on Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396824).

Comment: Can you share you spreadsheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1syanGAMewhBUGwQdh65LYFrNf1EKGk66JfUQbY5vcfM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the following function:

```
function splitRows(sourceRange, targetCell) {
  var values = sourceRange.getValues(), result = [];
  values.forEach(function(v) {
    var m = v[2].match(/\d+/g);
    if (m) {
      m.forEach(function(d) {
        result.push([v[0], v[1], d]);
      });
    }
  });
  targetCell.offset(0, 0, result.length, 3).setValues(result);
}
```

The first argument is the range A2:C4 in your case, and the second one is top-left corner of the target range for the results.

The critical part is using of the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to extract and separate numbers from the last column. Then we can compose resulting array and place it back to the sheet.